# Creating bootstrap rows in when looping in list in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list as

```
@model IEnumerable<VideoViewModel>
```

I am trying to make two items in a row with a foreach loop in Razor.

**Here is an example of what I am trying to do:**

```
    <div class="row">
            <div class="statistics col-lg-3 col-12">
                            <div class="statistic d-flex align-items-center bg-white has-shadow">
                                <div class="icon bg-red"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                                <div class="text"><strong>Video 1 </strong><br></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="statistic d-flex align-items-center bg-white has-shadow">
                                <div class="icon bg-blue"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i></div>
                                <div class="text"><strong>Video 2</strong><br></div>
                            </div>

                 </div>

<!-- Second Column -->
     <div class="statistics col-lg-3 col-12">
                                <div class="statistic d-flex align-items-center bg-white has-shadow">
                                    <div class="icon bg-red"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                                    <div class="text"><strong>Video 3 </strong><br></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="statistic d-flex align-items-center bg-white has-shadow">
                                    <div class="icon bg-blue"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i></div>
                                    <div class="text"><strong>Video 4</strong><br></div>
                                </div>

                     </div>
    </div>
```

What I want to achieve with the for loop, is to to add a column of four columns two rows. Based on the number of items that I have in my list, add a maximum of four columns. If there are more than four column in a row, then add another row. Can someone please help with that logic?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to display video content in a row with a maximum of 4 columns then you can divide the screen in 4 with help of the bootstrap col-md class.

Send list from the controller to view, Here I am using viewbag without Model.

**In Controller**

```
var videoList = _entityOBJ.tblVideo.Tolist(); //Getting list to var object
ViewBag.videoList  =videoList ; //adding list to viewbag
```

**In View**

```
<div class="row">

    @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.videoList)
    {
        <div class="card col-md-3"> // divide screen in 25% (total ratio is 12, so 12/4=3)
            <div class="card-body">
      @item.ColumnOfVideoTableToBeDisplay  //specify the column name same as you database table
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</div>
```